# I made a comment model in Django. How would I go about making a comment reply model?

Tags: django, django-models

Here is my comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
```

How would I make another model that can reply to this comment model, then reply again to the replied comment. Please let me know if you need anymore detail on the question.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume this is a comment on a news article:

Add a parent field and a article field. Any comment record that does not have a parentID means it is directly commenting on the article and any comment with a parentID means it is a comment/reply to another comment.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    article = models.ForeignKey(article)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Comment, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This means you could have 1 record with no parentID (meaning it is a direct comment to the article), 50 comment records with a parentID of that other comment with no ID (representing they are replies), and then you could have more records that have parentID's that are ID's of those comments.

This also has the benefit of not needing another model class. A 'reply' is the same as a comment, just without a parent.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
class Reply(models.Model):
    reply = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    comment = models.ForeignKey('Comment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)
```

You can then have multiple replies for each comment.

Use the parent foreign key to record when someone replies to a reply.

For example, this is what you would expect in your database:

First comment and reply - 
Comment 1
Reply 1
Parent Null

Reply to that first reply - 
Comment 1
Reply 2
Parent 1

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how can I have someone reply to that reply comment?

Comment: @MitchellPottratz I've edited my answer, hope that helps?